# Git not showing star next to current local branch

Tags: git, git-branch, case-sensitive, git-checkout

I am new to git and have encountered a confusing situation.

In summary I am having trouble understanding how case-sensitivity works pertaining to branch names. For example I am on the master branch and create a new branch called AP-1025 with the command `git checkout -b AP-1025`, now I can do a `git branch` and I see that I am on AP-1025 as it has a star next to it.

Now lets say I make some changes on AP-1025, commit them, and switch back to master with `git checkout master`. I am back on the master and everything is fine, however if I now do a `git checkout ap-1025` (notice the lower case characters, and no -b, meaning a new branch was **not** created). It tells me I have switched to ap-1025, but this time when I perform a `git branch`, AP-1025 does **not** have a star next to it, and there is no branch appearing with a star next to it.

My confusion arises from the fact that git allows me to perform the `git checkout ap-1025` without complaining about a missing branch, so I assume the branch names are not case sensitive. However `git branch` does not indicate I am truly on the AP-1025 branch, which indicates that some part of the branch naming/commands **is** case sensitive.

Am I truly on the AP-1025 at that time? How come `git branch` does not show any branch with a star next to it? Is this a bug in the `git branch` command?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you use Windows. Git stores branches as files on disk. Also branch name is stored in the HEAD reference as a name. On Windows if you create file `AP-1025` you could open it later as `ap-1025` which causes misbehaviour in git as names actually differ, but Windows allow to open the file to read branch info.

Comment: Ah, yes I should have specified I am using Windows 7 git through the cmd, git bash also seems to behave the same in this manner. I suppose the only way to avoid this confusion is to always consider case-sensitivity of branch names when using git on windows?

Comment: @J.Schei Just always consider case-sensitivity ;) On Linux it will just fail (branch not found), on Windows it will be buggy.

Comment: Any way to fix this situaltion?

Comment: @Robert not sure, but worth trying `git gc` it should pack branches into a special file as a content, not a file name, it so may fix the problem. If not - just delete the branch and create with correct case.